# While deployment, Cannot load `Rails.application.database_configuration` Could not load database configuration. No such file -

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-platform

I'm having the following error while trying to deploy the ruby application on google cloud using command `gcloud app deploy` But it works when I run the following command (while being in the project directory) `bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb`, so, `config/database.yaml` file exists!

Error Log

```
Step #1: rake aborted!
Step #1: Cannot load `Rails.application.database_configuration`:
Step #1: Could not load database configuration. No such file - 
Step #1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:105:in `database_configuration'
Step #1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:128:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
Step #1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
Step #1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
Step #1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:28:in `block in on_load'
Step #1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `each'
Step #1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `on_load'
Step #1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:118:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
Step #1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
Step #1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
Step #1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
Step #1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
Step #1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
Step #1: /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
.....
.....
.....
```

app.yaml

```
runtime: ruby
env: flex
entrypoint: bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb
```

Anything am I doing wrong? Please advise.

Comment: Maybe it requires the database configuration for a specific environment. I assume you have the development configuration in your `config/database.ym`. You may need to specify `production` configuration for Gcloud

Comment: it can't find the database file where the variables are set.

Comment: @muaaz, so your app is not being able to find your config/database.yml, can you run this app locally, if so can you post your database.yml and the structure of your project? I suggest also that you check these examples of [database.yaml](https://gist.github.com/erichurst/961978), i think it would help.